# Adobe Digital Editions 2.0.1 vs. Windows 10

Tags: windows, adobe-digital-editions

After moving to a new physical computer I fail to run ADE 2.0.1 (downloaded from https://www.adobe.com/support/digitaleditions/downloads.html , as always). Despite the previous system with similar stats but noticeably older hardware being able to run it consistently no matter what (it suffered multiple upgrades and even was once replaced from Win10 Home to Win10 Pro), the new one (Home), both out of the box and after upgrading to 1903, just cannot start it; the app tries no more than two seconds and disappears without showing GUI.

The standard solutions, including: change directory of install, use compatibility/run as admin, delete and/or move My Digital Editions folder, came all useless. The only hack solution I was able to concoct was the insanity of installing VirtualBox with an unlicensed Windows 7 inside, where it all runs (this, by the way, proves my hardware runs it in principle). Also, current version 4.5.1 installs and easily runs. But such a roundabout way of behaviour is overly complicated.

Does anyone have another possible solution, involving rewriting some registry keys, or maybe running ADE in some command-line mode, or any other method to make it start? I am starting to consider dual boot to Ubuntu as accessing it through Wine…

Answer (score 0):

ADE 2.0.1 runs fine on my 1903 Windows 10 machine. You're most likely missing a required runtime. Installing the [latest MSVCRT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150) runtimes *might* fix this problem.

If it didn't, open a command prompt windows, change to the ADE directory (usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Digital Editions 2.0`), run DigitalEditions.exe and copy any error messages.

Comment: The list of what I now have installed of frameworks is at https://imgur.com/a/IYn93t4 , Fig. 1. Fig. 2 shows my .NET Framework turned on in Windows Components, which is probably why it does not even try to run the installer. There is no error messages, no anything: even from command-line it just immediately disappears.

Comment: Maybe your "My Digital Editions" folder contains a corrupted file? Try to locate your "My Digital Editions" folder and delete all files in it. 

If that doesn't work, install [ADE 3.0](http://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/digitaleditions/ADE_3.0_Installer.exe) in a different folder. If you can't run ADE 3.0 either, most likely another system library is missing. 

In rare cases antivirus programs can also interfere with ADE. Try to temporarily disable your antivirus program. If ADE works, you'll have to add ADE to the exclusion list of your antivirus program.

Comment: As I already mentioned before, I tried all the possible manipulations with My Digital Editions folder, including adding one from the properly installing 4.5.1. ADE 3.0 does not run either, there is no antivirus but Windows Defender.